# List a target directory in C

Tags: c, shell

So I am tasked with creating a shell. I have the functions working correctly (e.g. dir, clear, quit, etc.), but I have a question about the 'dir' function. Currently 'dir' works fine. It lists the files of the directory that the program is located in. What I want to do is list the directory of another location. Is there a way to that?

I have yet to create the change directory command. I was wondering if my problem would be solved through that instead. Any help is appreciated.

Side note: The instructions state that I "will need to provide some command line parsing capability to extract the target directory for listing." I have no idea what that is, but maybe someone could enlighten me.

Comment: `DIR *d = opendir("/any/path/you/want");`

Comment: Nice. I like the way you listed that. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't really how a shell works, all a shell does is output the stdout and stderr from started processes. The only "command" is cd which changes the working directory to start programs in. Every other "command" is actually just a program, usually added to the PATH so it can be called from anywhere. You of course start programs by typing there file name, followed by any arguments.

Comment: Actually clear and quit would also be examples of actual commands other than programs. Dir would just be a program though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at GNU's [Simple Directory Lister](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Simple-Directory-Lister.html) example code, which uses `opendir()`.

To parse command line arguments, take a look at your `main()` function:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Use the `argv[]` pointer and `argc` integer value to determine the number of and character pointers of arguments.

Comment: Oh ok. I was wondering if I had to use arguments at all. Thanks.